# Move record from development to production in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cloudkit-environments

I have plenty of record manually preloaded to CloudKit but in the development environment.

When I deployed development environment, records were not moved into production environment. It is really annoying. Any easy way to move records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no easy way to migrate your records. You cannot link an app both to production and to development. The only workaround is downloading all records from development and storing those records in a file and then switch to production and upload the contents of that file to production.

Comment: When you sign your app for distribution (Ad hoc or App Store) it will connect to production

Comment: Select Project -> Build Setting -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity - Change to iOS Distribution .. I tried this .. but still the data is getting uploaded to CloudKit Development environment.

Comment: you should go to the apple developer portal and create a distribution certificate. Then you should use that certificate like you did above. They you should create an archive and install that on your device (preferably by using testflight to make sure you have the right installation)

Comment: thanks a lot . created a dummy app with correct bundle id and distribution certificate, with all assets. submitted to iTunes connect. downloaded the app through test flight beta testing and finally uploaded the assets to production environment 